# BitTorrent protocol does not seem to match with reality

Tags: network-protocols, bittorrent

I'm having some problems implementing a tracker - I'm using [PHPTracker](https://github.com/tcz/PHPTracker) as the underlying library, but this is of little importance right now.

As written in the [BitTorrent spec](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#tracker-get-requests-have-the-following-keys), a client should send a `info_hash` GET parameter among some others. Instead, I'm receiving the following parameters:

```
{
    "peer_id":"-AZ4702-WyiDalpWGJno",
    "supportcrypto":"1",
    "port":"19952",
    "azudp":"19952",
    "uploaded":"0",
    "downloaded":"0",
    "left":"22",
    "corrupt":"0",
    "event":"started",
    "numwant":"75",
    "no_peer_id":"1",
    "compact":"1",
    "key":"fdn0htAH",
    "azver":"3"
}
```

The same parameters came from both Vuze as well as uTorrent. I'm quite confused here, since some parameters are in the spec and others are not. What's going on here?

Comment: extra parameters are extensions, check the other specs.

Comment: I imagine you're failing to parse the query string properly. What's the actual GET request you get?

Comment: @Arvid Actually it's the json_encode of the string (don't ask why). The parameters were actually correct - turns out `json_encode` doesn't really like bencoded strings.

Answer (score 1):

This query is meaningless, the info_hash key is essential. Per @Arvid's suggestion, your library is not correctly parsing the request, or parsing it some way that doesn't meet your requirements.